# regex failing at hash symbol

Tags: python, regex, bottle

I am trying to use @route to match a string of any letters, symbols, and/or special characters.

Here is what I have:

```
@route('/create/<mypath:re:[#!@$%^&*()\_\-.,A-Za-z0-9//:]+>')
```

The problem is that once the hash symbol is reached, the rest of the string is ignored.

For example:  `test123!!!.....he#llo!` will only match: `test123!!!.....he`

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Do you want only that specific subset of characters? Because the \S character class will match all non-whitespace.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, here is the answer to my question: http://osdir.com/ml/python-bottle-general/2011-11/msg00012.html

Comment: The provided link is dead